Why is my second storage device not showing up on this PC, even though it shows up on UEFI/BIOS?
Why is my second storage device not showing up on this PC, even though it shows up on UEFI/BIOS and on Device Manager? It shows up hereBut not here?Does it have to do anything?Shows up here as well

Worth having a look at windows "disk management", sometimes a hard drive can be recognised partly but not have been assigned a drive letter. There's options to assign a drive letter in "disk management" too.

That then brings up the disk management window
See here re options to assign drive letter.. try right clicking on those areas in the disk management window to get that menu. Try right clicking where it says disk0 / disk 1 e.t.c. too.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-drive-letter
